# Invalid Hook in reactJS Using Auth0

Tags: reactjs, auth0

I have an app.js with the following const function:

```
  const serverUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;
  const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
  const callEndpoint = async (props) => {
    const {endpoint} = props;
    const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
    try {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        console.log('endpoint is:', `${serverUrl}/${props.endpoint}`);
        const response = await fetch(
          `${serverUrl}/${props.endpoint}`,
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
  
        const responseData = await response.json();
  
        console.log(responseData.message);
      } catch (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
      }
};
```

Further down in the render:

```
<Button variant="outline-primary"  onClick = { (e) => {callEndpoint({endpoint:"get_timestamp_public"})}} >Fetch Public Data</Button>
```

It works fine.

However, when I try to move my endpoint into a new js file called 'api_funcs.js':

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';

const UseAPI = (props) => {
    const {endpoint} = props;
    const serverUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;
    console.log("I am in here");

    const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();
    

    const callEndpoint = async () => {
        const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
        try {
           // const token = await getAccessTokenSilently();
            const response = await fetch(
              `${serverUrl}/{props.endpoint}`,
              {
                headers: {
                  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
                },
              }
            );
      
            const responseData = await response.json();
      
            //setMessage(responseData.message);
            console.log(responseData.message);
          } catch (error) {
            //setMessage(error.message);
            console.log(error.message);
          }
    };
    

}
export default UseAPI;
```

The `const { getAccessTokenSilently } = useAuth0();` throws me an error of:

```
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component.
```

I don't understand -- isn't my UseAPI a function component? What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

- As you are not breaking the Rules of Hooks.

There might be two common reasons because of which you might be seeing this error:

1. **You might have mismatching versions of React and React DOM.**

You might be using a version of *react-dom (< 16.8.0)* that doesn’t yet support Hooks. You can run

```
> npm ls react-dom
```

in your application folder to check which version you’re using.

2. **You might have more than one copy of React in the same app.**

In order for Hooks to work, the *react* import from your application code needs to resolve to the same module as the *react* import from inside the *react-dom* package.

If these react imports resolve to two different exports objects, you will see this warning. This may happen if you **accidentally end up with two copies** of the react package.

If you use Node for package management, you can run this check-in your project folder:

```
npm ls react
```

If you see more than one React, you’ll need to figure out why this happens and fix your dependency tree. For example, maybe a library you’re using incorrectly specifies *react* as a dependency (rather than a peer dependency). Until that library is fixed, [Yarn resolutions](https://yarnpkg.com/lang/en/docs/selective-version-resolutions/) is one possible workaround.

You can also try to debug this problem by adding some logs and restarting your development server:

```
// Add this in node_modules/react-dom/index.js window.React1 =
require('react');

// Add this in your component file require('react-dom'); window.React2
= require('react'); console.log(window.React1 === window.React2);
```

If it prints *false* then you might have two Reacts and need to figure out why that happened. [This issue](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/13991) includes some common reasons encountered by the community.

This problem can also come up when you *use npm* link or an equivalent. In that case, your bundler might “see” two Reacts — one in application folder and one in your library folder. Assuming *myapp* and *mylib* are sibling folders, one possible fix is to run *npm link ../myapp/node_modules/react* from *mylib*. This should make the library use the application’s React copy.

Thus, running the command

```
 npm link <path_to_local_library>/node_modules/react
```

might solve your issue.

**Note**

In general, React supports using multiple independent copies on one page (for example, if an app and a third-party widget both use it). It only breaks if require('react') resolves differently between the component and the react-dom copy it was rendered with.

*Source React Doc*